# Get the date an Access table was created in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am using VB.NET and need a way to get the date a table was created in MS Access.  It is shown in Access under table properties so I am guessing I can retrieve that data somehow.

Does anybody have any idea?

Regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (DAO objects):

```
 CurrentDB.TableDefs("TableName").DateCreated
```

You would also need to have Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library reference added in your VB.net project.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.  Never thought of using DAO objects.  It is working great now, thanks.